# Chrome Extension setInterval or setTimeout because page loads too slow

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating chrome extension. Here's how it should work:

Open extension -> load new page in current tab -> read content from this page -> insert this content into extension html code (popup.html).

How it's working now:  Open extension(ok) -> load new page in current tab (ok) -> read content from this page (?) -> insert this content into extension html code (popup.html) (not working).

But when I close extension and open it again it works.
I'm think this is because page load is too slow and I need to set timeout or interval in step 3 or 4. I've tried setInterval and setTimeout functions but it failed.

Here is my popup.html (I've deleted unnecessary stuff):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="myName" content="empty">
</head>
<body>
page content
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
// Inject the payload.js script into the current tab after the popout has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'payload.js'
    });
    chrome.tabs.update(null, {url:"https://mypage.com"});;

});

// Listen to messages from the payload.js script and write to popout.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
document.getElementsByName("myName")[0].setAttribute("content", message);
});
```

payload.js:

```
// send the page title as a chrome message
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementsByTagName("META")[0].content);
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "MyName",
    "description": "empty!",
    "version": "0.2",
    "author": "me",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["popup.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "icons": { "16": "icon_16.png",
    "48": "icon_48.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png" },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

I've tried to apply `setInterval(function(){ code; }, 500);` to popup.js and/or payload.js but I doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing popup.js. Now payload.js is loaded after loading site in tab is complete. Here is my final popup.js:

```
 // Open https://mypage.com in current tab when popup has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
    chrome.tabs.update(null, {url:"https://mypage.com"});

});

// Listen to messages from the payload.js script and write to popout.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value = message;
});

// Inject the payload.js script into the current tab after mypage.com has loaded
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId , info) {
  if (info.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'payload.js'
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a background.js and put that in the manifest instead of popup.js.

Then reference popup.js from popup.html with

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

That way popup.js can access the popup.html dom.

I think that's all you need to do but didn't have time to try it.

Comment: And what should I put into background.js?